# PL/SQL handling of the null parameter in the dynamic sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am building dynamic sql in my procedure:

```
procedure my_proc(p_first VARCHAR2, p_second NUMBER, p_third NUMBER DEFAULT NULL, p_fouth NUMBER DEFAULT NULL)
IS
str varchar2(3200);
v1 VARCHAR2(20);
v2 VARCHAR2(20);
v3 VARCHAR2(20);
str2 varchar2(1000);

begin

str2:='SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2, my_func1(t2.c3, '||p_third||') FROM ';

if p_third=3 then
        str:= 't1,t2,t3 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t3.c1 and t1.c1=p_first ;' ;
elsif p_third=2 then
        str:=' t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=p_second ;' ;
else
        str:='t2 where t2.c1=p_second ;';
end if;

str2:=str2 || str;

dbms_output.put_line(str2);
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  str2 into v1,v2,v3;

--dbms_output.put_line(v1||','||v2||','||v3);

end;
```

where p_third is null, so the sql resulting is:

```
SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2, my_func1(t2.c3, ) FROM t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=p_second;
```

instead I need the following:

```
SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2, my_func1(t2.c3) FROM t1,t2,t4 where t1.c1=t2.c1 and t2.c1=t4.c1 and t2.c1=p_second;
```

whenever p_third is `NULL`. Not sure what is the best way to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CASE:

```
str2:='SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2, my_func1(t2.c3' ||
  case when p_third is null then null
       else ', ' || p_third
  end || ') FROM ';
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding one more check at top

```
IF p_third IS NOT NULL THEN
   str2:='SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2, my_func1(t2.c3, '||p_third||') FROM ';
ELSE
   str2:='SELECT t2.c1,t2.c2, my_func1(t2.c3) FROM ';
END IF:
```